# ctest/cmake search for a string in output file

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm converting some old tests to cmake/ctest and would like a test to fail if the output file contains a specific warning message.

In the past I would search the output file for a specific string. I'm already using execute_process to use the compare_files command. Is there a similar command for searching a file for a string?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can read the file into a variable using `file`. (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) and then use one of the `string` subcommands.

```
file(READ foo TMPTXT)

string(FIND "${TMPTXT}" "needle" matchres)

message(STATUS ${matchres})

if(${matchres} EQUAL -1)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "No match found")
endif ()
```

and then

```
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P findmatch.cmake
```

Specifics might be a bit different, but that's the general idea.